# :nth-of-type(3n+1) not working when different sibling present

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors

In this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IFrg3TPrMB), I want every 3n+1 `col-lg-4` to be cleared. It works when the `col-lg-12` is not present but this defeats the purpose of nth-of-type no?

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">col12 ignore</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">a</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">b</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">c</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">d</div>
  </div>
</div>

.col-lg-4:nth-of-type(3n+1){
    clear: left;
    color: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but it cannot be done easier with a rearrangement of cols, or an adjustment of their sizes? For instance, if this is coming out of PHP you could insert new rows dynamically in a loop.

Comment: There is no `nth-` class selector. These pseudo-classes work only on types and not any arbitrary selector.

Comment: type === element (short version)

Comment: You could consider the case(s) where there's one (two, etc) `.col-lg-12` `.col-lg-4:nth-of-type(3n+1), .col-lg-12 ~ .col-lg-4:nth-of-type(3n+2) { /* something */ }` (you must also cancel the rule for (3n+1) => `.col-lg-12 ~ .col-lg-4:nth-of-type(3n+1) { /* cancel */ }`) - [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CDX5ukGznN) - but any other solution will be more robust both in the rendered page and in your project code, less messy, etc ;)

Comment: The purpose of nth-of-type is which element type, not class, so if you change the `col-lg-12` to a span it will work

Comment: May I ask if you try to have _rows_ without using a _row_ div?

Comment: @Abhitalks can you write it as answer please so I can mark it as correct. Cheers